# Mercurial: no terminfo entry for setab/setaf

Tags: windows, mercurial, openssh, terminfo

I am SSHing from macOS into Windows and using Mercurial remotely. Whenever I run any `hg` command, I'm getting a bunch of warnings, starting with

```
no terminfo entry for setab/setaf: reverting to ECMA-48 color
warning: failed to set color mode to terminfo
ignoring unknown color/effect 'orange' (configured in color.ui.warning)
```

These warning messages completely overwhelm the screen and I can't find the actual output. Is there a way to

1. Tell Windows/Mercurial that I actually have a xterm-256color capable terminal (I'm using iTerm2 on macOS, or
2. Just use 16 colors, but suppress the warning messages.

PS. I don't get these warnings from Windows command prompt. But I need to SSH to save bandwidth (and use VS Code remote extension).

PSS. I don't really care too much about colors per se, but the underlines rely on color and they are useful for the commit hashes in Mercurial.

Thanks.